# Get additional info for Zillow Neighborhood Boundaries

Tags: geolocation, maps, zillow

I am trying to use Neighborhood boundaries data(shape files) provide by Zillow. 
files available at - http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm

I am able to read the provided .dbf files but it just have information about state, county, city, name, and region ID.

can some one please guide me to get latitude longitudes or polygon information from this .dbf files or even from shape files.
also how to read the provided shape files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [GetRegionChildren](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetRegionChildren.htm) API to get the Lat/Long and other details corresponding to a regionId.